# Extending maps of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

(I'm happy to work over an algebraically closed field....)

Let $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow Spec (R)$ be a (flat) family of proper, prestable curves where $R$ is a DVR.  Suppose the generic fiber is smooth and the special fiber, $C_0$, is reduced but may be reducible.

Given a finite map of curves $f_0: D_0 \rightarrow C_0$ with $D_0$ also prestable, can this be extended to some map on some family?

That is, is there a flat family of proper curves $\mathcal{D} \rightarrow Spec(R)$ and an $R$-morphism $f: \mathcal{D} \rightarrow \mathcal{C}$ which reduces to $f_0$ on the special fiber?

Perhaps such an extension is possible only after a ramified cover of $Spec(R)$?

If so, can it be arranged that the generic fiber of $\mathcal{D}$ is smooth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stated as such, the question is really too vague. 
For example, if $C_0, D_0$ are smooth of genus bigger than 1, and $f_0$ is purely inseparable, then $f_0$ can not lift to $R$ (even after extention) if $R$ has characteristic zero. Actually, as the generic fibers of $\mathcal C$ and $\mathcal D$ are equal to $g(C_0)=g(D_0)$, this will contradict Riemann-Hurwitz formula.

In [this survey paper](http://www.math.u-bordeaux1.fr/~liu/articles/tokyo.ps) you can find some sufficient conditions. For instance, the lifting property for finite generically étale morphisms of semi-stable curves are characterized.

Comment: My comment "too vague" was for the first version of the question... 

Comment: I will take a look at this reference... what happens if I keep making the question more specific, like requiring $f_0$ to be separable, or else the genus is small?

Comment: The answer for f_0 separable (=generically étale) is in the paper. What do you mean by small genus ? 

Comment: Say, g = 0 or g = 1.

Comment: Ah great!  Section 5 of your survey is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can extend an arbitrary morphism, even if the curves are prestable.

For instance, if  $C_0$ is a  quartic with one node  and the generic element is a smooth quartic then
you do have a morphism from a smooth curve of genus $2$ to  $C_0$ which does not extend, since any extension would map a curve of genus $2$ to a curve of genus $3$.

Comment: Yes great point - let me ask only about prestable curves - so that the singularities are at worst nodes.

Comment: I have slightly changed my answer to deal with prestable curves.

Comment: Yes, your comment explains why the condition in Qing Liu's referenced paper above, 4.11a is a necessary one.  Thanks!